# Accessing slide background in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

It seems straightforward, but I am not able to access the slide background.

```
from pptx import Presentation

presentation = Presentation()
slide_layout = presentation.slide_layouts[5]  # 5 corresponds to a blank slide
slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

print(slide)  # this prints: <pptx.slide.Slide object at 0x12ebbc280>

background = slide.background  # AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'background'
```

When I look at the [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/slides.html#pptx.slide.Slide), `Slide` object does have an attribute called `background`. Then why do I get the error `AttributeError: 'Slide' object has no attribute 'background'`?

I am using `python-pptx 0.6.2`. I must be doing something silly, but after some head-scratching I thought I would ask. Thank you!

Comment: @CodeWithRonny sorry, how does that help? Kindly explain bit more.

Comment: That's just unnecessary self promotion...

Comment: I've raised a flag on his other comments, he is pasting that link on multiple questions.

Comment: You need a newer version.  The `.background` property was added in 0.6.9.

https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#069-2018-05-08